# Why am I getting spaces inbetween my divs using this Masonry example code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I am trying to use Masonry for photos on my site, and I just added it at https://willhay.io/masonry/ to make sure everything was working before I tried to put it on the photos page. However, the divs are not lining up correctly and there is lots of blank space between the rows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Masonry Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mason.css"/>
  <script src="../masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

  <script>
    $('.grid').masonry({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: 160
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Masonry - columnWidth</h1>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 320px; }
.grid-item--width3 { width: 480px; }
.grid-item--width4 { width: 640px; }

.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 260px; }
.grid-item--height4 { height: 360px; }
```

This code is pulled straight from the Masonry website, with only extra functionality removed (resizing on click, hover states, etc.).

Comment: Which gaps are you talking about? I can't see any here: http://jsfiddle.net/713981bu/

Comment: These gaps. http://i.imgur.com/zHEjZvI.png They should fit together much

Comment: You want them to fit together vertically?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like them to do.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didnt have    $(document).ready(function() {, once I added that it worked. New js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 160
  });

});
```

Compared to just

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 160
});
```

which was incorrect and not loading correctly. 
I think it had something to do with masonry calculating the div positions before the actual page was loaded. Not really sure but I'm glad I figured it out finally :)

Comment: That explains why I couldn't get it working in JSFiddle, but couldn't get it *not* working in CodePen; IIRC CodePen doesn't require a `document.ready` statement for JavaScript, but JSFiddle does. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted!